# write and read two lists in one CSV file

Tags: java, csv, android-room, export-to-csv, read.csv

I wrote codes to export roomdatabase data to CSV file and import the data from it using storage access framework.It works but my roomdatabase has two entity class therefore  one more list.

So I want to write and read one more list in the same CSV file so that the user can backup and restore the data in one click each.

Is there the way for that?

Thank You.

export:

```
 public void exportCSV() {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        intent2.setType("text/csv");
        intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "db_backUp");
        startForExportResult.launch(intent2);
    }
```

import:

```
public void importCSV() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.setType("text/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "db_backUp");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startForImportResult.launch(intent);
    }
```

ActivityResultLaunche:export

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startForExportResult = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
                Intent intent = result.getData();
                if(intent != null){
                    Uri title = intent.getData();
                    recordList.clear();
                    db = Room.databaseBuilder(getContext().getApplicationContext(), DeckRoomDatabase.class, "deck_database")
                            .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
                    deckDao = db.deckDao();
                    List<Deck> decks = deckDao.getAllDecksForCSV();
                    recordList = (ArrayList<Deck>) decks;
                    if(title != null && result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK){
                        try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                                new OutputStreamWriter(
                                        getContext().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(title)))){

                            for(int i = 0; i < recordList.size(); i++){
                                writer.append("" + recordList.get(i).getName());
                                writer.append(",");
                                writer.append("" + recordList.get(i).getListCount());
                                writer.append(",");
                                writer.append("" + recordList.get(i).getDateTime());
                                writer.append(",");
                                writer.append("" + recordList.get(i).getParameter());
                                writer.append("\n");
                            }
                            writer.flush();
                            writer.close();
                            Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Backup Export to:" + title.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
    });
```

ActivityResultLaunche:import

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startForImportResult = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
                Intent intent = result.getData();
                if(intent != null){
                    Uri uri = intent.getData();
                    if(uri != null && result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK){
                        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                        getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)))){
                            String line;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                                String[] nextLine = line.split(",", 4);
                                if(nextLine.length != 4) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                    String name = nextLine[0];
                                    String listCount = nextLine[1];
                                    String dateTime = nextLine[2];
                                    String parameter = nextLine[3];

                                    deckDao.insertDeck(new Deck(name, Integer.parseInt(listCount), LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime),
                                            Integer.parseInt(parameter)));
                            }

                            Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Backup Restored...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: a) It is better to use a CSV library than using this `writer.append(",");` type of logic.  b) Why not have a separate file for each type of `List`?

Comment: Thank you for  your coment. a)I don't know about CSV library so I'll learn from now. b)When have a separate file for each type of List,users have to backup and restore two files(decklist and its contents,wordlist).But is it the better way?

Comment: I've actually tried to make two CSV files and method to call them at one click(onoptionsitemselected menu) a while 
 ago.Though I have to tap twice in the picker,the move is not bad. It might be the better  way than packing two lists in one file.